# Printing SQL Query In PreparedStatement in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I need to see the query being sent to Oracle from a Java program. In the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, toString() does the job, but the same does not apply to prepared statements from Oracle JDBC implementation. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Log4Jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/). This sits between your JDBC driver and the application, logging all DB traffic that goes back and forth. It's driver-agnostic, so need for driver-specific logging code.

Extremely handy, and would be even handier if it supported DataSources, but sadly it doesn't.

Comment: It was very helpful, I could not follow the installation instructions on the site, but I managed to get the debugging information I needed through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `getOriginalSql()` method returns the String being sent to Oracle.

Comment: In JDBC, I wouldn't rely on vendorspecific methods.

Comment: Thanks, it returns the string in the prepared statement, but without the set columns (question marks show up in the output).

Comment: @BalusC, can you elaborate on that statement?